# What use is Visual Studio Compile button?

Tags: c#, .net, build, compilation, visual-studio-2017

It can be added through `Tools->Customize->Commands->Add Commands`. It's under `Build`.

[image]

Since I added it to toolbar it's been disabled. Shortcut is `Ctrl+F7`. No documentation at all. What is it there for? What does it differ from `Build`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the `C++` compiler:

In a C++ project it will be enabled and it will `compile` you project:

Here is an image of the option in a standard C++ console application, it is there by default:

[image: A C++ console application]

For more info about `compiling` or the build steps in a typical `C++` environment, see: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work#6264256)

Comment: OK, clear. Just wondering. Why would you compile instead of build? Any different output?

Comment: @Jude You need to read the linked documentation if you're unfamiliar (which you probably are) with how C++ compilation / linking works.

Comment: @Jude: Yes, the output of the compiler is different then the one of the linker. The output of the linker is a full blown "runable" thing (depending on the target platform) while the compiler's output is just some raw machine code. Since linking can be a heavy process, sometimes it is faster to just "compile" and not to perform a full build, including the linking.